# PHP bug in if-else-if condition?

Tags: php

For debugging I've entered two echos to an if-else-if section in a method:

```
if ( $options instanceof Zend_Config ) {
    $options = $options->toArray();

    echo "1st condition true<br>";

} else if ( ! is_array($options) ) {


    echo "2nd condition true<br>";
    exit();

    throw new Bvb_Grid_Exception('options must be an instance from Zend_Config or an array');
}
```

The crazy thing is the output I'm getting is:

```
1st condition true
2nd condition true
```

**Can you explain this?!?!**

Comment: @user522350: To verify what netcoder said ("you are calling that routine twice"), insert `echo "called<br>";`. If it doesn't help: Are you sure that this is exactly your code?

Comment: Add an `echo 'Running my code.';` before the first `if` and check how many times it passes through there.

Comment: print a debug_backtrace in the elseif block

Comment: Just as a rule of thumb, if you see something you don't understand, the first response shouldn't be to posit something wrong with a basic language structure that millions of people have used billions of times.

Comment: @Paul: make that "gazillion times" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only explanation is that you are calling that routine twice.

The problem doesn't come from that piece of code you posted. It's something else.